# superclass mismatch for class when namespacing admin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey I am trying to namespace a bunch of controllers that I only want admins to be able to access. For example, I want routes like admin/products or admin/categories, but when I call any of those controllers located in my controllers/admin folder, I get the following error message

```
superclass mismatch for class CategoriesController
```

If I restart the server right after, I get this

```
Unable to autoload constant Admin::CategoriesController
```

and

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Admin::CategoriesController
```

These are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for :admins
  namespace :admin do
    resources :categories, :except => [:new, :show]
    resources :products
  end

  resources :products
  resources :carts, :only => [:show]
  resources :line_items, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  # Shop controller
  get 'shop/index    

  # Admin controller
  get 'admin/index'
```

This is my categories controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_admin!

    def index
        @categories = Category.all
        @category = Category.new
    end

    def create
        category = Category.new(categories_params)
        if category.save
        flash[:notice] = "You have added a new category"
        redirect_to categories_path
    else
        flash[:error] = "An error occured"
        render "index" 
    end
    end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    if @category.update(categories_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Succesfully updated #{@category[:name].titleize}"
      redirect_to categories_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "An error occured trying to update #{@category[:name].titleize}"
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    if @category.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "You succesfully removed #{@category.name}"      
    else 
      flash[:error] = "An error occured trying to remove #{@category.name}"
    end
    redirect_to categories_path
  end

  private

    def categories_params
            params.require(:category).permit(:name)
        end

end
```

This has been troubling me for some time now so any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to `namespace` the Controller class :

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
```

which is why you receive `Unable to autoload constant Admin::CategoriesController` error as Rails is looking for namespaced class `Admin::CategoriesController` and what you have is `CategoriesController`

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when the timeout is over :)

Comment: yep will do    fsafaf

Comment: Woooooow, thanks a ton from 8 years into the future!